# for which constants function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

$$f(x)=(x^2+a^2)^{(1/2)}\;\;|x|>1$$
$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c\;\;|x|\le 1$$

Function may not be continuous in $1$. So I have to check for which $a,b,c$ $\lim_{x\to1^{+}}(x^2+a^2)^{(1/2)}=\lim_{x\to1^{-}}ax^2+bx+c=(1+a^2)^{(1/2)}=a+b+c$, right?

Anyway, I don't know how to do this and I don't know how to deal with such problems.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to have them continue at both -1 and +1. 
$$(1+a^2)^{(1/2)}=a+b+c$$
$$(1+a^2)^{(1/2)}=a-b+c$$
So that:
$$b=0$$
$$c^2+2ac=1$$